# How to replace a file with its first part?

Tags: ant

Given the file prep.js with contents:

```
head
middle
tail
```

And the build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="abc" default="build">
  <target name="build">
    <replaceregexp file="./prep.js"
                   match="(.*)(middle)(.*)"
                   replace="\1"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Running "ant" leaves the file prep.js with:

```
head

tail
```

But I expect:

```
head
```

How do I get what I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) mentions a flag that treats the file content as a single line. You also may not need to match the middle word as the pattern should only keep the first line, so you can try:

```
<replaceregexp file="./prep.js"
               match="([^\r\n]*)(.*)"
               replace="\1" flags="s" />
```

`[^\r\n]` matches all characters except newline characters.